# ngrx- default values being overwritten through spread operator?

Tags: javascript, angular, immutability, ngrx-store

I am working on an ngrx selector that converts a section of the state tree into a view model.  As a simple example, in my state tree I have an array of `manager`.  Thus I have the following setup for my state tree, and view model-

```
export interface Manager {
    id: string,
    name: string
}

export interface AppState {
    managers: Manager[]
}

export interface ManagersVM {
    byId: {[key: string]: Manager},
    allIds: string[]
}

export const defaultManagersVM: ManagersVM {
    byId: {},
    allIds: []
};
```

Then in my selector, I have:

```
export const selectManagersVM = createSelector(selectManagers, (data) => {
    let mgrsVM: ManagersVM = { ...defaultManagersVM };
    for(let mgr of data.managers) {
        mgrsVM.byId[mgr.id] = mgr;
        mgrsVM.allIds.push(mgr.id);
    }
})
```

The problem I am running into, is that the line:

```
let mgrsVM: ManagersVM = { ...defaultManagersVM };
```

seems to not be making a copy of defaultManagersVMs properties.  (a console.log of defaultManagersVM after running the selector shows that it now has a non-empty byId and allIds).  I was under the impression that the spread operator within a newly defined object would create a copy, but that appears to be wrong.  How can I ensure that defaultManagersVM does not get mutated in my selector.

Answer (score 1):

The spread operator [does not make a deep copy of nested objects](http://www.bambielli.com/til/2017-01-29-spread-operator-deep-copy/), JavaScript does not have this functionality by default. An option is to use an external library (I.e. [Lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#cloneDeep), which supports deep cloning).

Alternatively, you can write your own recursive deep cloning function, if you require some particular functionality that's not covered by other libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a recursive **deepClone** method I picked up somewhere that seems to do the job

```js
export function deepClone(state) {

  if (Array.isArray(state)) {
    const newState = [];
    for (let index = 0; index < state.length; index++) {
      const element = state[index];
      newState[index] = deepClone(element);
    }
    return newState;
  }
  if (typeof state === 'object') {
    const newState = {...state};
    Object.keys(newState).forEach(key => {
      if (newState.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        const val = newState[key];
        newState[key] = deepClone(val);
      }
    });
    return newState;
  }

  return state;
}
```

You may also want to apply **deepFreeze** to anything that should not mutate. You get an error, but at least it's at the point of mutation.

```js
export function deepFreeze (o) {
  Object.freeze(o);

  Object.getOwnPropertyNames(o).forEach((prop) => {
    if (o.hasOwnProperty(prop)
    && o[prop] !== null
    && (typeof o[prop] === 'object')
    && !Object.isFrozen(o[prop])) {
      deepFreeze(o[prop]);
    }
  });

  return o;
}
```