# State variable modified even when using spread operator

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx

I am using Angular 5 and ngrx with rxjs 5.5.
I have a property in the state called selection, which is an object with a filters property.

In one effect I am trying to make a copy of the current selection in a new variable 'filters', and modify the 'something' property.

When I run the code I see the selection slice of the state is being modified to the value set in the effect even if I am not modifying this slice directly and I am using the spread operator.

I have also tried using a for loop instead of map and the result is the same.

// effects.ts

```
// Initialise filters using the spread operator
const filters = [
       ...selection.filters // Taken from the store
];

// Filters is a list of objects of type {key: {something: string}}
filters.map(filter => {
    for (const key in filter) {
        if (filter.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
              filter[key].something = this.auxService.get(filter[key].something);
        }
    }
    // At this point selection.filters in the store has been modified
});
```

Comment: Spread will only create a *shallow* copy, you'll end up with a new array of references to all of the old filters.

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50103170/ngrx-default-values-being-overwritten-through-spread-operator/50103227#50103227)